# C++ Piping ifstream into stringstream

Tags: c++, file, ifstream, stringstream, istringstream

I am overloading my istream operator, so I can replace `std::cin` with my object. I know I will have to feed it an empty stringstream for the final output to work.

I would like to feed an `std::ifstream` into a `std::stringstream` as so:

```
while(ifs >> ss) {}
```

Is this possible? Here is an example prototype code:

```
friend istream & operator >> (istream & is, Database & db)
{
    ifstream ifs;
    ifs.open(db.inputFilename_, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!ifs.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Couldn't read " << db.inputFilename_ << endl;
        return is;
    }
    while (ifs >> db.iss)
    {}
    ifs.close()
    return db.iss;
}
```

I am not interested in any answers that start with "use Boost" :) This is a purely standard C++ project. Thank you for any help or pointers.

Right now I am getting:

```
error: invalid operands to binary expression ('ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>') and 'istringstream' (aka 'basic_istringstream<char>'))
```

Comment: Let me rephrase that for you ;)

Comment: Why do you have a stringstream member, and what is this supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply do this:

```
 if(ifs){
     db.iss << ifs.rdbuf();    
     ifs.close();
 }
```

Comment: How will this fare with a huge input file?

Comment: Your new example doesn't work with an istringstream, but works with a normal stringstream. I am testing it out right now. BTW thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry for that. Just use this, its slighty faster than `std::copy`.

Comment: This works perfectly, and is *really* fast! Thank you again for your time, it is very much appreciated.

Comment: Faster things are not platform independent and I guess you want that.
However this stays as elegant as possible with respect to the speed.

Comment: I always do: c++ standard(platform independant) > elegance > speed. In the case of my personal projects. Fortunately what you posted is also speedy :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) with an [`std::istream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) for `std::cin` and [`std::ostream_iterator`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/ostream_iterator) for the `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <sstream>

void redirect(std::ifstream &is, std::stringstream &os) {
    is >> std::noskipws;
    std::istream_iterator<char> begin(is);
    std::istream_iterator<char> end;
    std::ostream_iterator<char> out(os);
    std::copy(begin, end, out);
}
```

Note that this copies the entire file into the `std::stringstream`, and thus for really large files that can't fit in memory, this will fail. The `rdbuf` solution that NaCl gave will similarly have an issue with very large files.

You can solve the large file problem by not reading all of the input at once. However, this will most likely require you to restructure your code inside your parsers. Without more detail on their implementations, I can't point you in the right direction.

Comment: I am not sure I get what you mean. Basically don't overload istream operator?

Comment: Please do! I have a few spare keyboards, want me to mail one? :D

Comment: `std::copy(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(db.iss));`

Comment: You don't need to overload anything.

Comment: Well the whole idea is to make it as elegant as possible. This way, I interact with different parser objects simply by doing something like: while(ss >> *database >> *gutenbargParser >> *reader) {}

Comment: You can still overload for the parsers.

Comment: Hmmm, so you suggest just a usual method that returns a ostringstream? I may try that, as I have to pipe an empty stringstream to get the overload working.